# How can I push different view controllers for different push notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I recently started working push notifications into my application, and a good amount of digging has gotten me as far as being able to do device-to-device push notifications, and then being able to execute a function when a user taps on the notification they receive. An example may be that once a user taps on a push notification, a new viewcontroller is pushed on top of the navigation stack, and the user is taken to that viewcontroller. My question now is: How can I now have different functions execute for different notifications?

For example, in my app, the user can send/receive friend requests, messages, and matches. For each of these notifications, the app should push a different view controller onto the navigation stack.

I'm using Firestore for my database and my app is programmatic rather than storyboard, and I'm not using Scene Delegate.

So far I have searched through the apple documentation, stack overflow and on YouTube but am struggling to find a clear solution.

The closest post to mine I could find was this post:
[How to add different actions depending on the category defined in incoming remote notification payload? Swift UPDATED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579999/how-to-add-different-actions-depending-on-the-category-defined-in-incoming-remot)

and I also found this documentation somewhat helpful:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types

But despite these posts being close to what I want, they focus on the user having multiple actions (i.e. a notification alerting a user of a meeting, will have options to 'accept' or 'decline', whereas what I want is to simply allow the user to tap on a notification that has no actions, and be taken to the relevant viewcontroller (I.e. if they receive a friend request, they are taken to the friendsList controller).

I have tried to replicate steps similar to those in the posts I linked above, but with my goal in mind, for example trying:

```
func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "FRIEND_REQUEST", actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let identifier = response.actionIdentifier

    switch identifier {

    case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
        print("The notification was dismissed")
        completionHandler()

    case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:


        if response.actionIdentifier == "FRIEND_REQUEST" {
            ChatLogController.select()
        } else {
            EditProfileController.select()
        }

        completionHandler()

    default:
        print("The default case was called")
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

The params I'm sending:

`let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : token,
                                   "collapse_key" : "type_a",
                                   "click_action" : "FRIEND_REQUEST",
                                   "notification" : ["title" : title,
                                                     "body" : body],
                                   "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
        ]`

Note: 'click_action' is just the firestore equivalent to 'category' (I have also tried using category instead of click_action as a param) - but yea none of my attempts so far are working, the above code just sends me to EditProfileController, so I'm assuming it didn't recognise the notification as having 'FRIENDS_REQUEST' category - any ideas ?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you give an example of another question on stack overflow you read about this and how your questions is different? I'm having having trouble understanding how your use-case is different

Comment: Have updated OP @SwiftRabbit